# convert several 2 dimensional data into 3 dimensional

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, concatenation

I would like to combine several 2-D data into 3 dimensional data. I have 124 2-D data (151 x 151) now I want to combine all these data into 3 dimensional, so that it will be like this 124 x 151 x 151. The 2-D data contains NaN elements.

Comment: How or where do you have those several 2D data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate multiple 2D arrays into a 3D array, use the generalized concatenation function [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html), specifying dimension 3.

For example, given 2D arrays `A1,A2,...` of *equal size*:

```
M = cat(3,A1,A2,...)
```

Say you have `k` 2D arrays organized in a cell array, `C`, where each cell is a 2D matrix, all of size `M-by-N`:

```
M = cat(3,C{:});
```

Then `M` will be of size `M-by-N-by-k`.  Now if you want to go from `M-by-N-by-k`, to `k-by-M-by-N`, use [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) or [`shiftdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html):

```
Mn = permute(M,[3 1 2]); % my preference
Mn = shiftdim(M,2);
```

NOTE: An alternative to `cat` is [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html):

```
M = cell2mat(reshape(C,1,1,[]))
```

Comment: how do you organize k 2D into one cell array, C?

Comment: How do you have the 2d matrixes now?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i got the data from wave model. the model produce this kind of arrangement. therefore, in order to me to make an analysis, I need them in 3 dimension.